# Module luamplib Warning

Tags: metapost

After an update of Texlive 2019, the following code displays error messages while it was running before the update.
The objective is to reproduce the figure below.

[image]

```
   \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
   \usepackage{luatex85}
   \usepackage{luamplib}
   \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(0);

   numeric u;
   u = 10mm;

   pickup pencircle scaled 1pt;

   angle_radius := 8pt;

   def mark_rt_angle (expr a, b, c, d) =
       fill ((1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--origin--cycle)
       zscaled (angle_radius*unitvector(a-b))
       shifted b withcolor d;
       draw ((1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1))
       zscaled (angle_radius*unitvector(a-b)) shifted b;
   enddef;

% macro drawing a circular arc (Franck Pastor)

    vardef arc(expr theta_min, theta_max) =
      save theta, mystep ; 
      mystep = 1; theta = theta_min ;
      dir theta_min 
     for theta = theta_min+mystep step mystep until theta_max:
     .. dir theta endfor 
     enddef 

    z0=(4u,0);
    z1=z0 rotated 90;
    z2=z1 rotated 120;
    z3=z2 rotated 120;
    z4=0.5[z2,z3];
    z5=z3 rotatedaround (z2,180);
    z6=z3 rotatedaround (z2,90);
    z7=z3 rotatedaround (z2,-90);

    path triangle; triangle = z1--z2--z3--cycle;
    theta_min := 0;
    theta_max := 60;
    pair center; center = origin;
    r := 0.5u; 
    myeps := 0.25u ; path p, a, b;
    a = (center -- center + dir theta_min) scaled r shifted z2;
    b = (center -- center + dir theta_max) scaled r shifted z2;
    p := arc(theta_min, theta_max) scaled (r) shifted z2;

    fill b -- a -- p -- cycle withcolor green;
    fill triangle withcolor 0.8*white;
    fill b -- a -- p -- cycle withcolor green;
    mark_rt_angle (z3, z4, z1, green);
    draw z1--z4 withcolor blue;
    draw triangle;
    draw fullcircle scaled 2abs(z3-z2) shifted z2;
    draw z1 withpen pencircle scaled 4bp withcolor red;
    draw z4 withpen pencircle scaled 4bp withcolor red;
    draw z6 -- z7;
    draw z3 -- z5;

    label.bot(btex $A'$ etex,z4);
    label.llft(btex $O$ etex,z2);
    label.rt(btex $I$ etex,z3);
    label.top(btex $A$ etex,z1);
    label.lft(btex $I'$ etex,z5);
    label.top(btex $J$ etex, z6);
    label.bot(btex $J'$ etex, z7);

    endfig;    
   \end{mplibcode}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Which kind of error messages?

Comment: You are missing a `;` on the second `enddef`..

Comment: @Thruston I'm confused, sorry for the noise. By cons, I have a question for the figure: how to extend the segments [JJ '], [II'] and [AA '] as in the figure ? Thank you both who made me want to learn Metapost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (somehow) lost a `;` from your source code....

```
vardef arc(expr theta_min, theta_max) =
  save theta, mystep; 
  mystep = 1; 
  theta = theta_min ;
  dir theta_min for theta = theta_min+mystep step mystep until theta_max:
     .. dir theta 
  endfor 
enddef;  % <---------------- you had lost the ; from here
```